# Bootstrap slider not working.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am starting on Bootstrap and finding it hard to figure out what the error is. The slider is appearing fine, the next and prev buttons are working, but the image isn't sliding, its staying still. The link changes when clicking the Prev or Next buttons the slide isn't changing or moving. It seems to be a very minute error, not yet able to figure out what the error is.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-example">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slider-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slider-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slider-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="slider/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="slider/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="slider/slide3.jpg" alt="Slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#carousel-example" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#carousel-example" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Did you include the necessary javascript?

Comment: Yes, I have added the CSS link code to head section and the JS link code provided by getbootsrap.com right before the closing body tag.

Comment: @HishamMubarak Have you included jQuery before BootStrap JS?

Comment: No, where can I find that code from?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Didn't even know there was a jQuery code that needed to be added to get sliders working. Got the code, added it to header, and the slider is working fine.